# Como publicar uma aplicação no IIS com Certificado de Cliente

Tags: iis, ssl, certificado-digital, iis-7

Bom dia,

Preciso alterar no IIS e colocar para que o Cliente quando acessar meu site, requira um certificado válido e valide para que no servidor onde vai consumir o serviço identifique se existe nele.

Eu configurei o SSL para Require no IIS, criei um certificado de cliente e adicionei no MMC, porém qualquer pessoa está conseguindo acessar meu serviço, mesmo que não tenha um certificado de cliente que seja valido para a lista do servidor.

Comment: Você chegou a desabilitar autenticação anônima nas configurações de autenticação do web site?

Comment: Siim, está desabilitado :(